# Can you use CLIPS to run on 3-valued logic?

Tags: clips

Running `if not X, assert Y` with no initial fact resulted in `Y`.

From this I thought that CLIPS was a 2-valued logic. Is there a way to enable 3-valued logic in CLIPS?

Comment: I don't think so.  But maybe you could use FuzzyCLIPS to do that.

Comment: Yes, you can use FuzzyCLIPS for either certainty or fuzzy values.